# How to launch a node with a parameter in ROS2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Migrating ros1 package to ros2 and couldn't figure how to launch with a paramter in ros2.

With ros1 I have a launch file that refers to a config file and from cpp code I use node.getParam

**launch file:**

```
<launch>
    <arg name="node_name" default="collector" />
    <arg name="config_file" default="" />
    <node name="$(arg node_name)" pkg="collector" type="collector" respawn="true">
      <rosparam if="$(eval config_file!='')" command="load" file="$(arg config_file)"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

**config file:**

```
my_param: 5
```

**cpp code:**

```
double my_param = 0;
n.getParam("my_param", my_param);
```

My question is how would that translate to ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311456/how-to-launch-a-node-with-a-parameter-in-ros2?/) by [ezra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38095/ezra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-12-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way I do it:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import EnvironmentVariable
import os
import launch_ros.actions
import pathlib

parameters_file_name = 'default.yaml'

def generate_launch_description():
    parameters_file_path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1]) # get current path and go one level up
    parameters_file_path += '/config/' + parameters_file_name
    print(parameters_file_path)
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='example_pkg',
            node_executable='example_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[
                parameters_file_path
            ],
         ),
    ])
```

config file in the /config folder:

```
 example_node:
        ros__parameters:
            some_int: 41
            log_severity: 1 #0-debug, 1-info, 2-Warn, 3-Error, 4-Fatal
            a_string: "Hello world"
            some_lists:
                some_integers: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                some_doubles : [3.14, 2.718]
```

in the cpp file:

```
ExampleNode::get_parameter_or("log_severity", severity_level , 0);
```

---

Originally posted by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) with karma: 78 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternative to `parameters=[parameters_file_path]`, one can specify the parameters directly with

```
parameters=[
    {"param1": "value1"},
    {"param2": "value2"}
]
```

as stated [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-CPP/#cppparamnode)

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1